# How to "open" a module with a button and close it by clicking the same button or outside of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that will act as a popup for users to sign in or register on a website I'm working on. As it stands, I have an element (#header--account--module--toggle) that, when clicked, opens the account module (#header--account--module). I am using the toggleClass() function to "open" this module (toggling the class .toggled). When the module is open and the user clicks on the toggle button again, the module closes.

What I can't figure out how to accomplish is to allow the module to be "closed" when a user clicks outside of the module when it is "open."

Here is my existing JS code:

```
function accountModuleToggle() {
   $('#header--account--module--toggle').on('click', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
     $('#header--account--module').toggleClass('toggled');
   });
   // close modal on click outside at anywhere
   $(document).on('click', function(e) {
     if ( $('#header--account--module').hasClass('toggled') ) {
       if (!$(e.target).closest("#header--account--module").length > 0) {
         $('#header--account--module--toggle').removeClass('toggled');
         $('#header--account--module').removeClass('toggled');
       }
     }
   });
 }
accountModuleToggle();
```

This code seems to clash; both scripts are fired at the same time, and I cannot figure out how to specify that the document click outside of the module should only remove the class .toggled from both elements if the module contains the class .toggled.

Comment: One idea is to put a `blurring` div that covers the rest of the document. Then you put your `modal` div on top of it (using css positioning and maybe z-index) then, whenever you click on that `blurring` div, you close the modal. I've seen multiple sites doing something like this.

Comment: That's a solid idea; thank you!